# Devise confirmable: Token is invalid error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

Been looking for past 3 hours... setting up confirmable email it protrayed as being easy but its is FAR from that. Anyway, I have fought through slew of errors and undefined maethods and variables and have wrestled this thing to send me something... However I cannot confirm it. I have looked under the hood in the confirmations controller to no avail... It just does not confirm right. I dont know what I am doing wrong here but it consistently redirects me to "Resend confirmation instructions" page...

UPDATE: Got hold of the error that is being generated at its the infamous Invalid token error. Again hour of research solved nothing I keep hearing that you need to use @token just like I do in my view... and it supposed to make it work but it does not.

Controller: Default Devise confirmations controller:

```
    class  ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  # GET /resource/confirmation/new
  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new
  end

  # POST /resource/confirmation
  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(resource_params)
    yield resource if block_given?

    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      respond_with({}, location: after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    else
      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end

  # GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
    yield resource if block_given?

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_flashing_format?
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
    end
  end

  protected

    # The path used after resending confirmation instructions.
    def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
      new_session_path(resource_name) if is_navigational_format?
    end

    # The path used after confirmation.
    def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
      if signed_in?(resource_name)
        authenticated_root_path(resource)
      else
        unauthenticated_root_path
      end
    end

end
```

Mailer view:

```
 <p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

Routes piece:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations', sessions: 'sessions', confirmations: 'confirmations'}

devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do

    root :to => 'homepage#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end

  unauthenticated :user do
    root :to => 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

New Confirmations vew

```
<h2>Resend confirmation instructions</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: confirmation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Resend confirmation instructions" %></div>
<% end %>
<%= devise_error_messages!(:email) %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Also, I have reworked devise error helper to have it display custom errors (Dont know may that is what messing it up but here it is:

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!(field)
    return nil if resource.errors.empty?
    messages = resource.errors.full_messages_for(field).map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    if resource.errors.full_messages_for(field) != []
      html = <<-HTML
    <div class="alert alert-error alert-block"> <button type="button"
    class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
      #{messages}
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
    else
      return nil
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after 10 hours of fightting I decided to restrt from scratch and have made it work on local as well as on heroku. Follow this tut for Rails 4 and Devise 3.2.4:   https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users. Then i got Undefined router error for a good while so I look at the registrations controller and replaced the 6 or 7 lines found in the default version of it heres the link to another tut that explains it better https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29:

Registrations controller action (Working)

```
# The path used after sign up for inactive accounts. You need to overwrite
# this method in your own RegistrationsController.
 def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
 end
```

Viola! It went through without any hassle. So something that should only take 5 min only taken me 10 hours. That's efficiency right there!

Also I got it to work with mobile format just in case some of you have problems with it:

confirmations controller:

```
# GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
    yield resource if block_given?

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_flashing_format?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html{redirect_to unauthenticated_root_path}
        format.mobile {redirect_to unauthenticated_root_path, notice: 'Confirmation success!'}
      end   
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html{render :new}
        format.mobile {redirect_to unauthenticated_root_path, alert: 'Failure, already confirmed'}
      end
    end
  end
```

If you have more technically correct answer post it and I will accept it if its better than mine!