# Devise password reset works in production but not in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, password-recovery

Same goes with confirmable but that's another question. ([Devise confirmable: Token is invalid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128144/devise-confirmable-token-is-invalid-error)) This is my local server output

```
Started PUT "/users/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-05 00:25:21 -0400
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"aa0iVP0Yy5F+QUG2WdifKjlWWLFupFQ95v6TM4pdhRE=", "user"=>{"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "passw
ord_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Reset Password"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = '687acf9f5b67f4a683220dce5bc411eb605a28ba43c751771b8bb24d08780d34'  ORDER BY "users".
"id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered devise/passwords/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 58ms (Views: 43.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Code is EXACTLY the same as on heroku app however in heroku I am able to reset the password and in local it just keeps rendering edit password. Here are the environment files: Note that email setting for user and pw are changed for reasons

Production:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.assets.precompile += ['active_admin.css']
  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://tracker-demo2.herokuapp.com/" }

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.eager_load = true
config.assets.digest = true


  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            'some@gmail.com',
  password:             'Not tellin ya!',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }

end
```

And Development:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
  config.eager_load = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            'some@gmail.com',
  password:             'Not tellin ya!',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }

end
```

Comment: Are you sure you're logged out locally when you click the link? I always cut and paste development reset password links into a private browser window so there's no chance of a session already established.

Comment: I have tried that, and yes I explicitly click logout which destroys the session. It only happens in development as with confirmations and anything token related in devise.